# Is it possible to sort an ArrayList by index?

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<Car> carsArray` which contain objects with `ID` and `Name`. I can sort it by `ID` and `Name` using `Collections.sort`:

```
carsArray.sort(comparing(Car::getName));
carsArray.sort(comparing(Car::getID));
```

it works fine. But I want also sort by index in Array. Or in other words get back this Array as is by showing the new added positions on top of this Array. When I show this Array first time it's showing as is from new added positions to last. After sort it i don't know how I can make it unsorted back. Remark - `ID` is not equal to the `Index`.

```
{ID:15,Name:BMW X3}      //index = 2
{ID:27,Name:Audi Q3}     //index = 1
{ID:20,Name:Toyota Rav4} //index = 0
```

After restarting view it shows unsorted from last index as I want. To add objects in it I use `notifyItemChanged()`.

Comment: In essence, the `ArrayList` is _always_ sorted by indices: the indices define the location of the objects. If you wanted to "restore" these locations after a sort operation, you would need to store the old order in some form (e.g. a `Map` or a copy list).

Comment: I use sort in view. If I `recreate` view it shows as is.

Comment: If you need the original order then don't sort the list itself. Sort a copy of it and use that for displaying the values

Answer (score 0):

## Make a copy of array

> After sort it i don't know how I can make it unsorted back.

You cannot.

A `List` by definition keeps each element in a specific “slot”, each slot identified by index number.

If you sort the list, you move the contents (an object reference) from one slot to another. After sorting, there is no way to know the previous slot assignment.

If you care about both the new order *and* the old order,  copy the list before sorting.

You can make an unmodifiable list by calling `List.copyOf`.

### Example

For brevity, we define a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) for your `Car` class.

```java
record Car( int id , String name ) { }
```

And your example data. Note that [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E,E)) returns an [unmodifiable list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable).

```java
List < Car > carsOriginal =
        List.of(
                new Car( 15 , "BMW X3" ) ,
                new Car( 27 , "Audi Q3" ) ,
                new Car( 20 , "Toyota Rav4" )
        );
```

[Reverse that original order](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)). Understand that we are turning the array on its head, upside down. We are *not* sorting by the content of the elements.

```java
List < Car > carsOriginalReversed = new ArrayList <>( carsOriginal );  // Create a new modifiable list from our original unmodifiable array. We are copying *object references* here, not copying objects.
Collections.reverse( carsOriginalReversed );  // *NOT* `Collections.reverseOrder`.
```

Now let's sort by content of the elements. For brevity of syntax, let's use streams to sort the elements, [producing a new unmodifiable list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()).

```java
List < Car > carsById = carsOriginal.stream().sorted( Comparator.comparing( Car :: id ) ).toList();
List < Car > carsByName = carsOriginal.stream().sorted( Comparator.comparing( Car :: name ) ).toList();
```

For clarity, let's reformat that code, wrapping lines.

```java
List < Car > carsById = 
    carsOriginal
    .stream()
    .sorted( 
        Comparator.comparing( Car :: id ) 
    )
    .toList();

List < Car > carsByName = 
    carsOriginal
    .stream()
    .sorted( 
        Comparator.comparing( Car :: name ) 
    )
    .toList();
```

When run:

```
carsOriginal = [Car[id=15, name=BMW X3], Car[id=27, name=Audi Q3], Car[id=20, name=Toyota Rav4]]
carsOriginalReversed = [Car[id=20, name=Toyota Rav4], Car[id=27, name=Audi Q3], Car[id=15, name=BMW X3]]
carsById = [Car[id=15, name=BMW X3], Car[id=20, name=Toyota Rav4], Car[id=27, name=Audi Q3]]
carsByName = [Car[id=27, name=Audi Q3], Car[id=15, name=BMW X3], Car[id=20, name=Toyota Rav4]]
```

Understand that copying a list does *not* copy the contained objects. A `List` is a collection of *object references*, not *objects*. Our four lists seen in this example all point to the very same original `Car` objects. After the `List.of(`, we do *not* instantiate any more `Car` objects in the subsequent lines.

Comment: That's the problem. I'm not displaying the array itself, but a copy of it. I sort it with buttons. This array is an a favourite array from the main data array.

Comment: @Vitamin I don’t understand your comment. If you have a copy, then you have the original order in your original array. So what is the point of your Question?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I stuck on finding the way how to sort by position index or make the Array unsorted back, when you said that it's impossible i start to look the way of working with copy, and the easiest way was given in answer provided down by marcinj

Comment: my Array find objects in main Array which is marked as "Favourite" and shows them in view. I misunderstood that it's a copy.

Comment: Still unclear. An array cannot “find” objects in another array. I have no idea what ”Favourite” is. And you have never described any “view”.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is what you are after but you can leave alone carsArray and instead create an index sorted the way you want. Next time you will insert new element to carsArray, you will recreate index array.

Index array will look as follows:

```
ArrayList<Integer> inds = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < carsArray.size(); i++) {
    inds.add(i);
}
```

then you need custom comparators to sort indexes:

```
Comparator<Integer> byName = (i1, i2) -> carsArray.get(i1).getName().compareTo(carsArray.get(i2).getName());
Comparator<Integer> byID = (i1, i2) -> Integer.compare(carsArray.get(i1).getID(), carsArray.get(i2).getID());
```

then you sort index array using:

```
Collections.sort(inds, byName);
```

or:

```
Collections.sort(inds, byID);
```

Remember to recreate index array each time you add new element to carsArray.

Finally to print all the cars using index array use:

```
for (Integer index : inds) {
    System.out.println(carsArray.get(index));
}
```

This way carsArray will always have original order, the way items were inserted.

Another aproach, might be easier, is to keep a copy of the original array:

```
ArrayList<Car> originalCarsArray = new ArrayList<>(carsArray);
```

you can always easily bring back original cars array this way:

```
carsArray = new ArrayList<>(originalCarsArray);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used a copy of Array for sorting it and bring back the original. I used 
`ArrayList<Car> originalCarsArray = new ArrayList<>(carsArray);`
and deed sorting with it and for recover the original I used refreshing the view